# NSDateFormatter does not work with the months

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm manipulating variables of type Date/String and I have a problem with it.

I receive in input a date as string with this format (2015-08-24) and I would like to have in output this date format (Sat, 25 Jan) as string.

I have this function :

```
    private func dateFormatter(s : String) -> String{
       let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
       var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(s)!

       var newDateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
       newDateFormat.dateFormat = "EEE, DD MMM"
       return newDateFormat.stringFromDate(date)
    }
```

Executing:

```
var d = dateFormatter("2015-08-24")
println(d) //Sat, 24 Jan
```

It is the wrong month, I don't know why.

When displaying each steps:

```
private func dateFormatter(s : String) -> String{
       println(s)  //2015-08-24
       let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
       var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(s)!
       println(date)   //2015-01-23 23:00:00 +0000 //Why day 23 whereas it is 24 in input?

       var newDateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
       newDateFormat.dateFormat = "EEE, DD MMM"
       return newDateFormat.stringFromDate(date) //Sat, 24 Jan
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Ysee

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for the format string? In particular, I strongly suspect that Y and D don't mean what you think they do.

Comment: Thank you ... In fact, I was wrong about the format. I confused with lowercase letters capital letters. ("yyyy-MM-dd") it works. Thank you !

Comment: Indeed. Basically, any time a date format doesn't work, the *very first* thing you should do is check your format against the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You messed up the format strings. This will work:

```
private func dateFormatter(s : String) -> String{
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(s)!

    let newDateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    newDateFormat.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM"
    return newDateFormat.stringFromDate(date)
}
```

Also, you shouldn't create `NSDateFormatter` object every time. Create an instance, store it somewhere and use it when needed.

Comment: I heard that date formatters are not thread safe, so you better store a separate date formatter instance for each thread (i.e. in a thread's dictionary)

Comment: On iOS 7 and later NSDateFormatter is thread safe. Source: [NSDateFormatter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter).